# Align images beside text

Tags: image, list, text, hyperlink, anchor

I want to align the images beside the text, and also they need to be click-able. How can I do this? Do I need to make unordered list?

Here is the whole page: http://jsfiddle.net/dzadze/68WrB/

```
<div>
<a class="pic_link" href="#">
<img src="http://f.cl.ly/items/3Q1e0G1Y2b2Q2U0N1g1q/fb.png">
</a>
<a href="#">Следете не <br>на FACEBOOK</a> &nbsp;
<a href="#" class="pic_link">
<img src="http://f.cl.ly/items/413J3G3e152p1g3W0t0l/ftp.png">
</a>
<a href="#">FTP Логин
</a>
<a class="pic_link" href="#">Што е Photobook</a>
<a href="#">Процес на изработка</a> &nbsp;
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the only solution but adding this to your css seems to work :

```
footer a{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like using [CSS floating](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/) would be a good place to start, based on what you've said.